# Div offset inside another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have situation similar to the one on image below, where DIV1 have `overflow-y: scroll` and one of child divs have class `active`. I don't know his position nor the offset from top. How can I find position of child div inside DIV 1 and scroll so far that child with active class is visible.

I don't mind if you use jQuery or plain js. But I prefer jQuery.

[image: Div inside div displayed]

Comment: Do you have a list of child divs that you are trying to insert a box-like div around?

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 Yes I do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `.position()` method of jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/position/

Providing your `div1` has `position: relative` set this method will give you offset from the top-left corner of your div1, so

```
$('.div1').get(0).scrollTop($('.div1 div.active').position().top);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Edited to reflect that scrollTop() is a function:  http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/